# Codeigniter load slowly on refresh on mac osx

Tags: performance, codeigniter

I recently installed fresh new copy on mac os x 10.7 and first loading  is really slow (0.08 sec) and then short refresh after that it load faster (0.0065sec) as well as any following request after that.It work fine for few minuets and then after 1min it does it again. It doesn't use database session and other virtualhosts without codeigniter load really fast.
I used that to install my development environment 
http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/ 
and that for php my admin 
http://www.djangoapp.com/blog/2011/07/24/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-os-x-lion/
(i never had this problem on linux or windows)

What can it be related to? Where to start debug this issue? It really annoying when developing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a short-timed caching issue?

i.e. the first time you visit the page, it is being loaded into cache, then all following requests are using the cache until it expires 1min later.

Check your headers